# Regex replace escaped characters

Tags: regex

I would like to define a regex pattern which replaces escaped characters with the corresponding value.
For example the string

> xy\tz\\x

Should be converted to

> xy{tab}z\x

The problem is how to handle things like

> xy\\\\\t

this string should become

> xy\\{tab}

I don't know how to create a pattern which matches only odd backslashes.

Comment: In .NET, use `Regex.Unescape`

Comment: it has to be in only one regex?

Comment: Got ABAP, no .net. Can be multiple regex patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that can be accomplished using a single pattern. To start, strip out collections of backslashes:

`s/\\\\/\\/g`

This replaces two backslashes with a single one.

Then you can just apply one pattern per escaped character:
`s/\\t/\t/g`

The trick here is to escape the backslash you want to replace. What this'll do is replace the literal string "\t" with a tab character.